# return to view after addModelError

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api

in this project i create cardGroup. in httpGet Method we get some needed info and pass to view to fill dropdown. when httpPost trigger if some field Date has Problem we must return error with addModelError but after return View, all ViewData Clear and Return Exception. how can handle this. just show error in view.

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("CreateCardGroup")]
    public ActionResult CreateCardGroup()
    {
        var discounts = 
         UnitOfWork.DiscountPatternRepository.GetNotExpireDiscountPattern();
        var discountDtos = discounts?.Select(c => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = c.PatternTitle,
            Value = c.Id.ToString()
        }).ToList();
        ViewData["DiscountPatterns"] = discountDtos;

        var serials = 
        UnitOfWork.ChargeCardSerialRepository.GetNotAssignedSerials();
        var serialDtos = serials?.Select(c => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = c.SerialNumber.ToString(),
            Value = c.Id.ToString()
        }).ToList();
        ViewData["ChargeSerials"] = serialDtos;

        ViewData["CardSerialCount"] = 
        UnitOfWork.GiftCardSerialRepository.GetNotUsedGiftSerials();

        return View();
    }



    [HttpPost]
    [Route("CreateCardGroup")]
    public ActionResult CreateCardGroup(CardGroupCreateDto dto)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View(dto);



        if(!UnitOfWork.DiscountPatternRepository
            .IsCardGroupDateInRange(dto.DiscountPatternId, 
             dto.ActiveFromDate, dto.ActiveToDate))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("ActiveFromDate", @"Error In Date.");
            return View(dto); <---Problem Here
        }

        var group = dto.LoadFrom();
        var insertedId = UnitOfWork.CardGroupRepository.Add(group);

        foreach (var rangeDto in group.CardGroupGiftSerialRanges)
        {
            for (var i = rangeDto.GiftCardSerialBegin; i <= 
                         rangeDto.GiftCardSerialEnd; i++)
            {
                var serial = 
                UnitOfWork.GiftCardSerialRepository.GetBySerial(i);
                if (serial != null)
                {
                    serial.CardGroupGiftSerialRangeId = rangeDto.Id;
                    serial.DiscountPatternId = group.DiscountPatternId;
                    UnitOfWork.Complete();
                }

            }
        }

        return Redirect("/CardGroup");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/827059/Data-Passing-Mechanism-in-MVC-Architecture) article:

> ViewData
>
> ```
> ViewData is a property of ControllerBase class.
> ViewData is used to pass data from controller to corresponding view
> Its life lies only during the current request. If redirection occurs, then its value becomes null. It’s required typecasting for getting data and check for null values to avoid error.
> ```

So what's happening is once you've done your post back to the server, you're now in a different request, meaning, that you need to repopulate your ViewData items so that their values are populated again, or else they'll be null.

So I'd recommend refactoring your Dropdown population method into a private method on your controller and then call that method in your post when you find a validation error or are just returning by calling `return View(dto)`.

If they're used in other controllers, you can add them to a `LookupService` or `LookupRepository` or even a general helpers class that contains your lookup logic (whatever fits into your UnitofWork pattern the best for you), to make them available to those other controllers, instead of having it as a private method as per my example.

So something like this for example:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("CreateCardGroup")]
public ActionResult CreateCardGroup()
{
    PopulateCreateCardGroupLookups();

    return View();
}



[HttpPost]
[Route("CreateCardGroup")]
public ActionResult CreateCardGroup(CardGroupCreateDto dto)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        PopulateCreateCardGroupLookups();
        return View(dto);
    }


    if(!UnitOfWork.DiscountPatternRepository
        .IsCardGroupDateInRange(dto.DiscountPatternId, 
         dto.ActiveFromDate, dto.ActiveToDate))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("ActiveFromDate", @"Error In Date.");
        PopulateCreateCardGroupLookups();
        return View(dto); <---Problem Here
    }

    var group = dto.LoadFrom();
    var insertedId = UnitOfWork.CardGroupRepository.Add(group);

    foreach (var rangeDto in group.CardGroupGiftSerialRanges)
    {
        for (var i = rangeDto.GiftCardSerialBegin; i <= 
                     rangeDto.GiftCardSerialEnd; i++)
        {
            var serial = 
            UnitOfWork.GiftCardSerialRepository.GetBySerial(i);
            if (serial != null)
            {
                serial.CardGroupGiftSerialRangeId = rangeDto.Id;
                serial.DiscountPatternId = group.DiscountPatternId;
                UnitOfWork.Complete();
            }

        }
    }

    return Redirect("/CardGroup");
}

private void PopulateCreateCardGroupLookups()
{
    var discounts = 
     UnitOfWork.DiscountPatternRepository.GetNotExpireDiscountPattern();
    var discountDtos = discounts?.Select(c => new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = c.PatternTitle,
        Value = c.Id.ToString()
    }).ToList();
    ViewData["DiscountPatterns"] = discountDtos;

    var serials = 
    UnitOfWork.ChargeCardSerialRepository.GetNotAssignedSerials();
    var serialDtos = serials?.Select(c => new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = c.SerialNumber.ToString(),
        Value = c.Id.ToString()
    }).ToList();
    ViewData["ChargeSerials"] = serialDtos;

    ViewData["CardSerialCount"] = 
    UnitOfWork.GiftCardSerialRepository.GetNotUsedGiftSerials();
}
```

Comment: very thank you. i want to do this but i think this is very bad code.

Comment: My pleasure. What's very bad? Doing the population in a method in the controller? I'd recommend you don't do it exactly like that but split out each lookup call into it's own method within some kind of repository, which you could then group for specific actions.